# Commit heroku - Not a git repository error

Tags: heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I have cloned my app from heroku to my computer and have made changes. Now, I'm trying to commit this changes...

I have logged in heroku by terminal and wrote: **git commit -am "add widget"
git push heroku master**

I'm getting the following error: **"not a git repository or any of the parent directories: . git"**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem entering in folder from my application